# repeater control causing Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: vb.net

I have read through many of the questions related to my situation but I have not found one that does. I currently have a repeater with 4 bound items to it, clicking on a button in the repeater causes my error, below is the markup and codebehind. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and the fix for it? (I have excluded the page decleration and just included the page_load event. let me know if i should cut and past full code in)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptFoo" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnfoo" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim items As New List(Of String)
items.Add("test1")
items.Add("test2")
items.Add("test3")
items.Add("test4")
rptFoo.DataSource = items
rptFoo.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Invalid postback or callback argument" with Databound controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293699/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-with-databound-controls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Invalid postback or callback argument" with Databound controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293699/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-with-databound-controls)

answers my question incase anyone else needs this

Answer (score 4):

That happens because the `Repeater` is getting datasource (binding) as you perform the `item` command operation. Just add `if(not ispostback)` to the `page_load` method.

Answer (score 2):

I will repeat the answer here so you don't need to link to

The problem is loading the data for the control in the page Load event and calling the DataBind() method. However it appears that if the DataBind() method is called before the events are raised the above exception is generated as the control naming has changed.

The solution is to change this to if(!IsPostback) DataBind() and then call the DataBind() method at the end of the event handler. You would need to call it most of the time anyway at the end of the handler to affect the changes.

If this is not your problem, and you are modifying controls client side using JavaScript, check out [this article](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/21/3153.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

'add post back method in your page load
If IsPostBack = False Then

end if

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).