# loop of buttons ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I've been stuck for the last two hours and need help.  I've tried every single example I could find online and none of them work.  I'm building a web page in `ASP.NET` and want to make a list of buttons.  Doesn't seem too hard right?  It's been causing me issues though.

This is my code:

```
<ul>
  <form id="tagloop" runat="server">
    <% foreach (string i in data)%>
      <%Response.Write("<li><button runat=\"server\" type=\"submit\" onserverclick=\"ClickTag\">" + i + "</button></li>");%>
  </form>
</ul>
```

If I remove the `Response.Write()` it only loops once but the one button it does generate actually works and calls the method on click.  Also, the variable i doesn't apply.

```
<ul>
  <form id="tagloop" runat="server">
    <% foreach (string i in data)%>
      <li><button runat="server" type="submit" onserverclick="ClickTag"> i </button></li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

Is there anyway I can get it to loop, have the text of i in data, and also call the correct function on click?  I haven't been able to find a balance of all three yet and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First add {} around the <li>, I didn’t think this would even work without it. You should never really use Response.Write and it definitely doesn’t work with server-side controls as you noticed.

Comment: What's your preferred solution. Do you want server side controls with code behind event handlers?

Comment: It possibly loops once because you have only 1 object in data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create server side controls, you're better off using an `asp:Repeater`:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="RepeaterButton" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" OnClick="RepeaterButton_Click"/>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if(IsPostBack) return;
    var data = new List<string> { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4" };
    Repeater1.DataSource = data;

    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

You have to write a bit more code, but you avoid adding to much logic into your markup and do not have to use Response.Write, which is prone to errors and typos.

You can even do this with strongly typed objects!
Let's assume you have a person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a method in your .cs file that returns a list of Persons:

```
IEnumerable<Person> Persons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield return new Person { FirstName = $"Foo{i}", LastName = $"Bar{i}" };
    }
}
```

You can then reference your object properties in your repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" ItemType="WebFormsSandbox.Person">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="RepeaterButton" Text="<%#: Item.FirstName %>  <%#: Item.LastName %>" OnClick="RepeaterButton_Click"/>

        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm getting an invalid postback or callback error.  I've tried changing multiple things to nothing different.  Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293699/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-with-databound-controls 
See my updated code for the Page_Load method. You need to add a postback check

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    <form id="tagloop" runat="server">
        <%
            List<int> data = new List<int>();
            data.Add(1);
            data.Add(2); %>
        <% foreach (int i in data)%>
           <%Response.Write("<li><button runat=\"server\" 
           type=\"submit\"onclick=\"ClickTag\">" + i + "</button></li>");%>
    </form>
```